# Uploading new version to ituneconnect with fastlane fails with error: Redundant Binary Upload

Tags: ios, fastlane

I am trying to upload new version to itunesconnect using fastlane. My lane code is the following:

```
lane :deploy do |options|
    increment_build_number  
    sigh
    gym(
      scheme: options[:scheme],
      include_bitcode: false
    )

    pilot

    version     = get_version_number(xcodeproj: "App.xcodeproj")
    build       = get_build_number(xcodeproj: "App.xcodeproj")
  end
```

It worked great until recently. However, recently i am receiving an error when the app begin uploaded to itunesconnect:

```
01:34:45]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version “1.2.8” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number."
[01:34:45]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90189: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build '334' for version '1.1.11'"
[01:34:45]: ERROR ITMS-90189: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build '334' for version '1.1.11'"
[01:34:45]: You have to change the build number of your app to upload your ipa file
[01:34:45]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.1.11' is closed for new build submissions"
[01:34:45]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.1.11] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.2.8]."
[01:34:45]: Transporter transfer failed.
[01:34:45]: 
[01:34:45]: ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version “1.2.8” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number."
ERROR ITMS-90189: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build '334' for version '1.1.11'"
ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.1.11' is closed for new build submissions"
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.1.11] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.2.8]."
[01:34:45]: ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version “1.2.8” can’t be imported because a later version has been closed for new build submissions. Choose a different version number."
ERROR ITMS-90189: "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with build '334' for version '1.1.11'"
ERROR ITMS-90186: "Invalid Pre-Release Train. The train version '1.1.11' is closed for new build submissions"
ERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.1.11] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.2.8]."
Return status of iTunes Transporter was 1: ERROR ITMS-90478: "Invalid Version. The build with the version “1.2.8” can’t be imported because a later vers\nERROR ITMS-90062: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [1.1.11] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously approved version [1.2.8]."
The call to the iTMSTransporter completed with a non-zero exit status: 1. This indicates a failure.
```

I tried reinstalling fastlane but it did not solve the problem. Also, uploading the ipa using the xCode Organizer works. How can i solve the problem in Fastlane?

Comment: Have you already tried incrementing the build version number? The error log indicates that you have a version 1.2.8 uploaded and you are trying to upload a version 1.1.11. Try uploading a version 1.2.9.

Comment: The version is correct. Uploading directly from xcode organizer works great so i knkow there is no problem with project settings

Comment: What about the build number? Can you move the get version/build code above pilot and add `puts "#{version}, #{build}` so that the version number and build values are printed before pilot?

Comment: I added the prints and moved the get version and build code. This is what i get: [18:03:46]: 1.2.9
[18:03:46]: 407

Comment: What about if you run the `get_ipa_info_plist_value` action with the path to the ipa and the CFBundleShortVersionString? It seems that `get_version_number` gets it from the product, and the built app has a different number

Comment: Not sure i understand how the command should look

Comment: Take a look at the source: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/get_ipa_info_plist_value.rb, specifically self.available_options and self.example_code